# Transfer data to hosted TFS

Tags: team-foundation-server

Microsoft has set up TFS hosting at [tfs.visualstudio.com](http://tfs.visualstudio.com).  We are looking to switch over but I'm not crazy about losing a lot of our check in history.

Searching through the online resources I don't see anything that talks about how to transition from your own TFS instance to theirs while preserving all this data.

Does anyone know whether it's even possible, and if so, how to accomplish this or even have a link to a document describing the procedure?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Apparently it is not possible.